# "Snake" populating a grid (list of lists)

Tags: python

Given a 5 x 5 grid and a list of objects (could be anything, integers for example)

How can I fill the grid in such a way that the sequence the grid is filled is:
A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, B5, B4, B3, B2, B1, C1, C2 etc, etc

So it kind of snakes around the grid.

The grid, in the python code is a list of lists, created using code shown below.

I've tried a number of different approaches using flags to reverse direction through the lists but all of them are messy.

```py
room = []
columns = 5
rows = 5

for x in range(columns):
    room.append(["0"] * rows)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the modulus operator to oscillate the direction of the range

```
room = []
columns = 5
rows = 5

for x in range(columns):
    room.append([])
    if (x % 2 == 0):
        start = 1
        stop = rows + 1
        step = 1
    else:
        start = rows
        stop = 0
        step = -1
    for y in range(start,stop,step):
        room[x].append(y)

print(room)
#result: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 4, 3, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: Thanks - I experimented with this and it seems a less messy approach to the stuff I tried before. When I have some working code I'll post the results.

Comment: Got it sorted. The modulus tip was the answer. I probably didn't;t explain what I was trying to do very well but here's the code doing what I wanted. Main difference is, for a couple of reasons I need to predefine the grid then fill items from a list into it. Pretty simple once I used modulus to change directions through the grid!

Answer (score 0):

You could create your grid by looping over rows of your dataset chunked by column size and using the modulus operator (as noted in the answer from [@AndrewYochum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/432519/andrew-yochum)) to alternate reversing each sublist. Note that you may need to add some checking and fillers if you need to accept input lists with fewer items than the grid size (input list items beyond the range of the grid will not be included).

```
data = list(range(25))
cols = 5
rows = 5
grid = []

for i, x in enumerate(range(0, rows * cols, cols)):
    grid.append(data[x:x+cols][::-1] if i % 2 else data[x:x+cols])

print(grid)
# [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [9, 8, 7, 6, 5], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [19, 18, 17, 16, 15], [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]]
```

Or as a list comprehension:

```
grid = [data[x:x+cols][::-1] if i % 2 else data[x:x+cols] for i, x in enumerate(range(0, rows * cols, cols))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working code

```py
room = []
columns = 3
rows = 3
items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

for x in range(columns):
    room.append(["0"] * rows)

for x in range(columns):
    if (x % 2 == 0):
        for y in range(rows):
            room[x][y] = items.pop(0)
    else:
        start = (rows - 1)
        stop = -1
        step = -1
        for y in range(start, stop, step):
            room[x][y] = items.pop(0) 

print(room)
#result: [[1, 2, 3], [6, 5, 4], [7, 8, 9]]
```